# BB86/92 spacer hollowtech Ultegra 8150

Tags: road-bike, crankset, bottom-bracket, chainline, canyon

I'm having some issues on my new road bike which I am setting up. It's a Canyon Ultima CFR frameset which came out of the box with the handlebars, Dura Ace 9200 wireless shifters and brake calipers.

I ordered a compatible Ultegra Di2 8150 groupset and I'm running a 11-30T cassette, 50/34 chainrings with 172.5 cranks.

However, when running on the three smallest cogs in the back and on the largest chainring in the front I'm getting some chain noise and some light vibration through the pedals when on the bike stand.

Shifting itself is great, already experimented with a slightly shorter chain but no results there. Derailleur hanger seems straight and not bent but might be worth double checking. Would be strange if this would come slightly bent out of the box.

I'm also thinking towards some sort of spacer to be used between the crank and the bottom bracket or even between the big chainring bolts itself to allow for a better chainline.

Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you see any rubbing or interference? Something's got to be causing the vibration. Also, have you tried riding the bike? It might just be a break-in issue that will go away shortly.

Comment: Not worth an answer, but I think it hasn't been unheard of that Shimano groupsets often run a bit rougher on the small cogs. I've had that too, and unless it is a real unhealthy noise, it can be perceived as noise and vibration. In the end, it's mostly an alignment issue or (slightly bent) derailleur, imo. Not sure if the Shimano factory lube is the greatest, so stripping that off the chain and applying some quality lubricant might also be worth a shot.

Comment: @DoNuT But big/small is a normal configuration that should not have any chain rub anywhere, and there shouldn't be enough force when freewheel pedaling on the stand to make noise anywhere near what seems to be the problem here.  Big/big or small/small crosschaining and I'd agree with you.  FWIW, in my experience the gooey factory Shimano lube will make things quieter.  Wiping off the excess with a WD40-soaked rag is probably a good idea - dirt and junk sticks to it like glue.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't mean rub or cross-chaining, just the big gears often running a bit rougher/noiser, especially under real load, even though indexing and shifting seems fine. I definitely had that on my mechanical 105 once, I think it finally went away after a bit of microadjusting, small cogs seem to be more sensitive to indexing in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check limit screws? For Di2 systems, you do make microadjustments first, and then check limit screws. Sounds to me like the front derailleur is rubbing to chain...